# Use a PC as a Miracast receiver?

Tags: windows, streaming, miracast

I have an Android phone capable of Miracast streaming and also Wi-Fi Direct, and a Wi-Fi capable laptop, currently running Windows 8.1 Pro and regularly reaching download speeds of 15 MB/s over BitTorrent and Steam - seems pretty capable of handling streaming.

Is there any way for my Windows laptop to function as a Miracast receiver?
I don't mind having to install Linux for this if needed.

Comment: What service are you getting 15MB/s torrent speeds with? We frequently get 2.8MB/s, and I thought that was fast.  What are you getting for ping, down and upload at speed at speediest.net?

Comment: 120 Mbps on wireless and wired. Pings of ~30 to the nearest server. Why are you surprised? I have friends with even better connections. 200 Mbps, 25 MB/s regularly, and pings which are extremely low even to much farther targets. I was outlining the capability of my laptop's networking card, not my internet connection.

Answer (score -1):

You can see [airserver](http://www.airserver.com/). I don't try it myself yet, but it's best way what I can find.

Also for streaming screen from mobile device to PC you can use TeamViewer.

Comment: Windows 10 will apparently be the answer. Also, I asked for Miracast specifically.